# Filtering according to matching values in two dataframes within a loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1 <- tribble(~Speaker, ~age, ~word, ~ID,
               "Alex", 10, "cat", "Alex_10",
               "Alex", 10, "dog", "Alex_10",
               "Alex", 10, "car", "Alex_10",
               "Alex", 11, "sheep", "Alex_11",
               "Alex", 11, "box", "Alex_11",
               "Alex", 11, "cup", "Alex_11",
               "Bob", 10, "cat",  "Bob_10",
               "Bob", 10, "dog",  "Bob_10",
               "Bob", 10, "car",  "Bob_10",
               "Bob", 11, "sheep",  "Bob_11",
               "Bob", 11, "box",  "Bob_11",
               "Bob", 11, "cup", "Bob_11")

df2 <- tribble(~Speaker, ~age, ~word1, ~word2, ~word_pair, ~ID, ~value,
               "Alex", 10, "cat", "dog", "cat_dog", "Alex_10", 23,
               "Alex", 10, "cat", "car", "car_cat", "Alex_10", 12,
               "Alex", 10, "dog", "cat", "cat_dog", "Alex_10", 23,
               "Alex", 10, "dog", "car", "car_dog", "Alex_10", 25,
               "Alex", 10, "car", "dog", "car_dog", "Alex_10", 25,
               "Alex", 10, "car", "cat", "car_cat", "Alex_10", 12,
               "Alex", 11, "box", "sheep", "box_sheep", "Alex_11", 56,
               "Alex", 11, "box", "cup", "box_cup", "Alex_11", 34, 
               "Alex", 11, "sheep", "box", "box_sheep", "Alex_11", 56,
               "Alex", 11, "sheep", "cup", "cup_sheep", "Alex_11", 21,
               "Alex", 11, "cup", "box", "box_cup", "Alex_11", 34,
               "Alex", 11, "cup", "sheep", "cup_sheep", "Alex_11", 21,
               "Bob", 10, "cat", "dog", "cat_dog", "Bob_10", 11,
               "Bob", 10, "cat", "car", "car_cat", "Bob_10", 87,
               "Bob", 10, "dog", "cat", "cat_dog", "Bob_10", 11,
               "Bob", 10, "dog", "car", "car_dog", "Bob_10", 45,
               "Bob", 10, "car", "cat", "car_cat", "Bob_10", 87,
               "Bob", 10, "car", "dog", "car_dog", "Bob_10", 45,
               "Bob", 11, "sheep", "box", "box_sheep", "Bob_11", 32,
               "Bob", 11, "sheep", "cup", "cup_sheep", "Bob_11", 24,
               "Bob", 11, "box", "cup", "box_cup", "Bob_11", 65,
               "Bob", 11, "box", "sheep", "box_sheep", "Bob_11", 32,
               "Bob", 11, "cup", "box", "box_cup", "Bob_11", 65,
               "Bob", 11, "cup", "sheep", "cup_sheep", "Bob_11", 24)
```

I want to run a loop through `df1` so that for each instance of `ID`, a new dataframe is created (saved as a list) that extracts each individual word produced at each time-point by each speaker, and matches it to `word_pair` values in `df2`. I have created a loop as follows:

```
 value_list <- vector("list", length(df1)) 

      for (i in unique(df1$ID)) {
       value_words <- df2 %>%                             
       group_by(Speaker, age) %>%
       filter(Speaker == df1$Speaker[which(df1$ID == i)] & 
              age == df1$age[which(df1$ID == i)]) %>%
       filter((word1 %in% df1$word |                 
               word2 %in% df1$word) &
               value <= 50) %>%                 
      distinct(word_pair, .keep_all = T)
      value_list[[i]] <- value_words 
        }
```

Expected output is as follows:

```
 value_list[[Alex_10]]

 # A tibble: 1 x 9
 # Groups:   Speaker, age [1]
   word1 word2 value Speaker age  word_pair ID
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>     <chr>      
   cat    dog    23  Alex   10    cat_dog   Alex_10
   cat    car    12  Alex   10    car_cat   Alex_10
   car    dog    25  Alex   10    car_dog   Alex_10
```

So that every combination of each word with each other word is listed only once

But I get the following error:

> Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
> x Input `..1` must be of size 4 or 1, not size 5.
> i Input `..1` is `&...`.
> i The error occured in group 1: Speaker = "Alex", age = "10".

Obviously the issue is with the `filter()` but I can't figure out how to change it and still get the output I need.

Comment: what is expected output?

Answer (score 0):

The following does what you want with a `left_join`, a `filter` (from `dplyr`) and finally a `split` (from `base`):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("Speaker", "age", "ID")) %>% 
  filter(value <= 50,
         word == word1 | word == word2) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  distinct(word_pair, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  ungroup()

split(df, df$ID)
```

Which gives

```
$Alex_10
# A tibble: 3 x 8
  Speaker   age word  ID      word1 word2 word_pair value
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1 Alex       10 cat   Alex_10 cat   dog   cat_dog      23
2 Alex       10 cat   Alex_10 cat   car   car_cat      12
3 Alex       10 dog   Alex_10 dog   car   car_dog      25

$Alex_11
# A tibble: 2 x 8
  Speaker   age word  ID      word1 word2 word_pair value
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1 Alex       11 sheep Alex_11 sheep cup   cup_sheep    21
2 Alex       11 box   Alex_11 box   cup   box_cup      34

$Bob_10
# A tibble: 2 x 8
  Speaker   age word  ID     word1 word2 word_pair value
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1 Bob        10 cat   Bob_10 cat   dog   cat_dog      11
2 Bob        10 dog   Bob_10 dog   car   car_dog      45

$Bob_11
# A tibble: 2 x 8
  Speaker   age word  ID     word1 word2 word_pair value
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1 Bob        11 sheep Bob_11 sheep box   box_sheep    32
2 Bob        11 sheep Bob_11 sheep cup   cup_sheep    24
```

Comment: This works for subsets of the data, but my actual dataset is really big, so I get an error "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 871.5 Mb", unfortunately!

Comment: Okay, in that case, does adding `first()` to your original code work? That is, use `first(df1$Speaker[which(df1$ID == i))` in the `filter()`, and the same for `df1$age`?

Comment: This works! Thank you! Would you mind explaining why adding `first()` here makes the difference?

Comment: Glad it works! Since `df1$Speaker[which(df1$ID == i)]` can be a vector of length more than 1, and `Speaker` is also a vector of more than 1, `Speaker == df1$Speaker[which(df1$ID == i)]` can give unexpected results. Since every entry of the right-hand side is the same, we can just take the first element to force it to length 1.